# How can I do a right outer join in a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails controller, I'm setting a variable like this:

```
@users = User.find(:all, :joins => family)
```

This gives me all the users that have families. What I want is exactly the opposite: all the users that **don't** have families.

I tried adding:

```
:conditions=> {:family => nil}
```

... but got an error.

What's the proper way to do a right outer join?

Answer (score 1):

If family is a related object, you'd want to check if the family_id is null in the conditions clause.

```
:conditions => "family_id IS NULL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly my Ruby is poor, but I believe when I ran into a similar issue, I was able to filter for NULL using the following

```
:conditions => "family IS NULL"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something other than the default inner join you need to pass a string as the `:joins` parameter with the sql fragment for the join that you want to do.